# Does "sock-puppet" always carry the meaning of abusive, non-main accounts? Is there such thing as a "benign sock-puppet"?

Tags: support, sock-puppets, multiple-accounts, terminology

Does "sock-puppet" always carry the meaning of abusive, non-main accounts? Is there such thing as a "benign sock-puppet"?

The source of my confusion is that the post ["What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388985/11107541) lays out rules for having multiple accounts, and in the title, says "*(i.e. sockpuppets)*", which seems inconsistent with the [tag wiki for sock-puppets on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/sock-puppets/info), which says "*A sock puppet is an extra account created in addition to the user's normal account, especially with abusive purposes.*", and [the Wikipedia page for sock-puppetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_puppet_account), which says: "*often used to refer to alternative online identities or user accounts used for purposes of deception*".

Is it wrong to call a non-main account that follows the rules for having multiple accounts (i.e., that isn't abusive) a "sock-puppet"?

Comment: Personally I see "sock-puppet" as derogatory (but well-deserved in the cases where it's being used accurately). If you had two accounts in, say, World of Warcraft, it would be pretty strange to call one of them a "sock-puppet". Multiple accounts are just multiple accounts. Sock-puppets are when you have a second account pretending to be someone else, but it's actually just you again. (i.e. it is your hand, in the sock, pretending to speak)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can SE codify or clarify sockpuppeteering in the Terms and Conditions and rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216813/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312820/282094

Comment: @Rob It does inadvertanly/indirectly! Thanks. I'm not sure if closing as a duplicate of that one really makes sense. Perhaps an answer linking to it with an explanation would be more appropriate?

Comment: I tend to refer to my other account as an 'alternate account' - which if this is a language thing is a good alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a test account that explicitly uses the term ‘sock’ and my name in the email address plus “… footwear is stinky” in a description field. It’s nice and descriptive, and fellow mods know who the owner is and why it exists. It’s not my main account; I sometimes need to test stuff at low rep, and not necessarily be recognised as “Martijn, the scary moderator”. It is a *benign* sock.

So yes, sockpuppets are not necessarily abusive. It’s a sock pretending to be a person. It just isn’t there to *defraud*.

However, that doesn’t mean that all extra accounts are sock puppets, nor is the term so ubiquitous that you can expect *everyone* to immediately understand what is meant by the term. So, I’d recommend sticking to “extra accounts” or other, similar more generic terms.

Comment: If that's the case, I wonder if the tag wiki could use a bit of re-phrasing to make it a bit more clear that the "especially" does not mean "necessarily". Someone with a better grasp of english than me could probably understand that, but I did not :P

Comment: @starball the English is fine to my ears, actually. Paraphrasing: *“Such accounts are often referred to as sockpuppets, especially when those accounts are used to defraud or abuse”*. It’s about the likelihood of the term being applied, abuse is more likely to such an account being “branded” as a sock.